# CSS - Position: relative; VS Position: absolute;

Tags: css, html5, css3, layout-responsivo

Boa noite galera estou com um problema em questão de deixar meu site responsive. O que acontece é o seguinte...

Tenho meu menu, que contem 2 **LI** "**ADICIONAR VALOR"** , "**CRIAR ROTINA**". E quero fazer com que eles fiquem responsivos, O **NAV** em que eles estão, eu consegui deixar responsivo, adicionando o  **Position: relative;**, porem quando eu reduzo a resolução do navegador somente o **NAV** ficam responsive, minhas **LI**, não redimencionam.

[image: *As bordas vermelhas são para ilustrar onde o CSS está afetando]

*As bordas vermelhas são para ilustrar onde o CSS está afetando.*

Já tentei colocar **Position: relative;** no **UL** nos **LI**, tentei tambem colocar **Position: absolute;**, porem nada ajudou, os meus **LI** continuam não redimencionando com a resolução do navegador.

Meu **codigo HTML** está da seguinte forma :

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="salario.html">Adicionar Valor</a></li>
        <li><a href="rotina.html">Criar Rotina</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Meu **codigo CSS** está desta forma:

```
body{
background-color: #e6a017;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
nav{

background-color: white;
top: -16px;
position: relative; 

}

nav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
nav a:hover{
color: white;
}
nav ul{
border: 8px solid red;
list-style: none;
text-transform: uppercase;  
right: -980px;
position: relative;
display: block;


}
nav li{

display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;  
margin-right: 10px;

}
nav li:hover{
background-color: #e6a017;
transition: 1s;

}
```

**RESOLVIDO**

Troquei a linha de codigo do css **"right: -980px;"** do **nav ul{}** por **"text-align: right;"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está puxando a lista para a direita com `right: -980px;`, o que é errado, fazendo com ela saia da área da nav. Para fazer algo responsivo, você poucas vezes irá usar dimensões com `px` (geralmente em elementos com tamanhos fixos ou que possam variar em determinadas breakpoints), e vai usar mais `%`, `em` ou `rem`. Mas a questão mesmo é esse right negativo de 980px, que não faz nenhum sentido e não tem a ver com responsividade.

Se quer alinhar as li's da lista para a direita, basta usar `text-align: right`:

```css
body{
background-color: #e6a017;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
nav{

background-color: white;
top: -16px;
position: relative; 

}

nav a{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
nav a:hover{
color: white;
}
nav ul{
border: 8px solid red;
list-style: none;
text-transform: uppercase;  
/*right: -980px;*/
text-align: right; /* aqui alinha o texto para a direita*/
position: relative;
display: block;


}
nav li{

display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;  
margin-right: 10px;

}
nav li:hover{
background-color: #e6a017;
transition: 1s;

}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="salario.html">Adicionar Valor</a></li>
        <li><a href="rotina.html">Criar Rotina</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Comment: Sensacional !! Funcionou aqui, eu estou aprendendo CSS3 ainda, então tem certas coisas que não eu domino !! Obrigadao Sam

Comment: Boa sorte meu jovem!